# How to clip a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I have a CAShapeLayer that i add a CAGradientLayer to, but there is no clipping about the shape of the CAShapeLayer.

Answer (score 4):

From your question it sounds more like you want to use a shape layer as a *mask* for a gradient layer. Create your CAShapeLayer adding a path to it. Then create a CAGradientLayer and set it's *mask* property. Then add your gradient layer to the layer hierarchy in your view.

```
[gradientLayer setMask:shapeLayer];
```